# Не добавляется запись в БД! Sql, c#, visual studio 13

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, winforms, update

Пытаюсь создать новую запись в БД, а ее нету. Для добавления раньше использовал `INSERT into...`, запись добавлялась, но не сохранялась. Прочитал, что нужно использовать для сохранения `UPDATE` но теперь запись не добавляется вообще. Может их вместе нужно использовать?

```
string connStr = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\LitMapPoltavaData.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
         SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
         try
         {

             //пробуем подключится
             conn.Open();
             SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
             cmd.Parameters.Clear();
             cmd.Connection = conn;
             cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Writers SET Id = @Id, Surname = @Surname, Name = @Name, Lived = @Lived, Birthplace = @Birthplace, ShortInfo = @ShortInfo WHERE Id = @Id";
             // Добавить параметры
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", tag);
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", tbSurname.Text);
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", tbName.Text);
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lived", tbLived.Text);
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Birthplace", tbBirthplace.Text);
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ShortInfo", tbShortInfo.Text);

             //Выполнить
             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

         }
         finally
         {
             conn.Close();
             conn.Dispose();
         }
```

Comment: update только меняет существующие записи, а insert только вставляет новые. да, используйте оба в зависимости от того что нужно в данный момент

Comment: для сохранения используйте `commit;`

Comment: @Mike можете написать как их сочетать нужно?

Comment: Есть три способа: 1. вам уже написали в ответе, даете update проверяете кол-во обновленных записей. 2. Делаете insert - если возвращается ошибка дублирования записи - делаете update. 3. Сами по каким то критериям даете в базу select count(*) что бы определить наличие записи и если она есть дать update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> как их сочетать

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Writers ...";
...
int recordsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

if (recordsAffected == 0)
{
  cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Writers ...";
  ...
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Премного благодарен!